# what command should i use to remove a particular segment from the sequence?

Tags: perl

In the string below:

```
AUGCGCGUUAAAAUGGGGGCCCCGCGCUUAGAACCGGAUG
      ^^                     ^^
First instance of GU    First instance of AG
```

How can I remove the segment starting from the first instance of `GU` to the first instance of `AG` from the string? In the example above, the output should be:

```
AUGCGCAACCGGAUG
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution operator [`s///`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html):

```
my $s = "AUGCGCGUUAAAAUGGGGGCCCCGCGCUUAGAACCGGAUG";
$s =~ s/GU.*?AG//;
print "$s\n";  # AUGCGCAACCGGAUG
```

Another alternative is to use [`index()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) and [`substr()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

```
my $s = "AUGCGCGUUAAAAUGGGGGCCCCGCGCUUAGAACCGGAUG";
my $i = index($s, "GU");
my $j = index($s, "AG", $i);

substr($s, $i, $j-$i+2) = "";
print "$s\n";  # AUGCGCAACCGGAUG
```

Comment: thanks but  can you tell me what does ".*?" stands for?